# Using xamarin language to test software element on appcenter

Tags: xamarin, testing, automation, uitest

Currently I am using xamarin to test a software running on HTC Android Phone 6.0.1. As for the numberpicker input, I have a problem, that is not working on the Set button to save the month.
The ways I used to affect the set button:

```
app.tap̣ (x => x.Id ("button1"));
```

With button1 is the id of the Set nut

```
app.tap (x => x.Text ("Set"));
```

Set is the value of the button's text property

```
app.TapCoordinates (230,400)
```

with 230 and 400 are the x and y values of the Set button
What should I do next?
Thank you all for your comments

Comment: Please use English in your question's title as well.

Comment: i am sorry this is my tittle
Use xamarin to automatically test the software on the app center

Comment: I meant the title of **this** question here on SO. Your question is in English, but your question's title is not. Please [edit] your question and also translate the title

Comment: Your app is written against the Xamarin platform, and what are you using for your automated testing?

Comment: i using xamarin uitest running on appcenter with device HTC 10 Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

try

```
app.Tap (x => x.Marked ("Set"));
```

Comment: i think app.Tap (x => x.Marked ("Set")); like app.Tap(x=>x.Text("Set"));

Comment: app.Tap (x => x.Marked ("Set")); it not working on HTC 10 Android 6.0.1 form set month and year not remove

Comment: when i user codes
while(app.Query(x => x.Marked("Set")).Count()>0 && i<=10)
{
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Set"));
i++;
Console.WriteLine("lan thu " + i);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
then result in the log file write repeat 11 times
lan thu 1
04-12-2018 09:15:46.572 +01:00 - 262589 - Query for Marked("Set") gave 1 results.
04-12-2018 09:15:47.880 +01:00 - 263897 - Using element matching Marked("Set").
04-12-2018 09:15:47.880 +01:00 - 263897 - Tapping coordinates [ 959, 859 ].
So i think Set Button not working

Comment: You can reach out to app center support for further help then. App Center support helps with UITest code issues. https://intercom.help/appcenter/getting-started/getting-help-with-app-center